# A player rolls four 20-sided dice, takes the lowest value, ignores the rest. What is the probability of this value at least 7?

Tags: probability, dice

I'm designing a tabletop game, and I need to figure out how to calculate a few probabilities:

1. Roll **3** 20-sided dice, take the **highest** value. What is the probability of it being 7 or higher? 15 or higher?
2. 1. Roll **4** 20-sided dice, take the **highest** value. What is the probability of it being 7 or higher? 15 or higher?
3. 1. Roll **3** 20-sided dice, take the **lowest** value. What is the probability of it being 7 or higher? 15 or higher?
4. 1. Roll **4** 20-sided dice, take the **lowest** value. What is the probability of it being 7 or higher? 15 or higher?

How can I do this? Could you explain to me how this works, or even better - give me a simple formula?

Comment: Instead of talking about "highest" and "lowest" values, it may be easier to think about "all" of the values having some property. E.g. in 3., you can say instead "What is the probability that all three dice have values $\ge 7$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you roll one $20$-sided die, then the probability that it is $7$ or higher is $\frac{14}{20}$. In general, to get a $k$ or higher, the probability is $\frac{21 - k}{20}$.

If you have $n$ $20$-sided dice and you take the **highest** value, then the probability that this max is $7$ or higher is the probability that at least one die is also $7$ or more. The complement is that all of the dice are $6$ or less, so we have:
$$
1 - \left( \frac{6}{20} \right)^n
$$

Likewise, if you have $n$ $20$-sided dice and you take the **lowest** value, then the probability that this min is $7$ or higher is the probability that all of the dice are $7$ or higher, so we have:
$$
\left( \frac{14}{20} \right)^n
$$

---

So to generalize...

> Roll $n$ $20$-sided dice, take the **highest** value. What is the probability of it being $k$ or higher?

$$
1 - \left( \frac{k - 1}{20} \right)^n
$$

> Roll $n$ $20$-sided dice, take the **lowest** value. What is the probability of it being $k$ or higher?

$$
\left( \frac{21 - k}{20} \right)^n
$$

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! Perfect answer, completely solved my problem! Thanks a lot!